# Landing page project failed. A lots of problems and mistakes. Can someone solve and also explain to me?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

https://codepen.io/oshimi/pen/jOBPQGr

1. The Navbar problem

I had to change the header's background color so the logo and the nav-links would have the same background. But, this cause a problem when I define a:hover. The background color(bordor) of hover style looks small, doesn't change the color of top and bottom navbar.

Another problem is navbar doesn't start from the top even tho I define margin 0. This also causes the email subscription section not seen.

2. align-items: center doesn't work.

I can't make the writings in the section with the id features placed at the center of the page. Text-align is working but that's not I am looking for. I want the paragraphs placed at the center just the way they are.
I also can't make this for the columns with borders.

```
<body>
<!--NAVBAR -->
<header>
    <div class="logo">
         <img
    id="header-img"
    src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/product-landing-page-logo.png"
    alt="original trombones logo"
  />
    </div>
    <nav id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="navlink">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlink">Details</a></li>
            <li><a class="navlink">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    
</header>
<div class="container-intro">
            <input type="email" required size="30" placeholder="Enter your email" class="input" id="email">
            <button type="Submit" class="submit" id:"submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
 <div class="container">
<section id="features">
  
    <div class="desc">
      <h2>Premium Materials</h2>
      <p>
        Our trombones use the shiniest brass which is sourced locally. This
        will increase the longevity of your purchase.
      </p>
    </div>
  
 
    <div class="desc">
      <h2>Fast Shipping</h2>
      <p>
        We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished
        making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.
      </p>
    </div>
  
  
    <div class="desc">
      <h2>Quality Assurance</h2>
      <p>
        For every purchase you make, we will ensure there are no damages or
        faults and we will check and test the pitch of your instrument.
      </p>
    </div>
  
</section>
</div>
<div class="detail"><!--3 columns at the center of page -->
    <section class="prices"> 
        <div class="easy">
            <h2>Easy</h2>
            <ol>
                <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="mid">
            <h2>Medium</h2>
            <ol>
                <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="hard">
            <h2>Hard</h2>
            <ol>
                <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<section class="video-section">
    <div class="video-div">
        <!--For the video h1 going to be on the left of the page and gonna be big and the video on the right -->
        <h1>The Video >>></h1>
        <div class="video">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5-9fAFjpncY?start=12" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</section>

<footer>
    <span>Copyright .....................</span>
    
</footer>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo&display=swap');

   *{
 margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
  }
  li{
list-style-type: none;

  }
  .container {
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
display:flex;
align-items: center;
background: orange;
height: 500px;

      }'
  header{
padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
     background: orange;
      position: fixed;
        width: 100%;

   }
   #header-img{
       width: 15rem;
       margin-left: -1rem;
    }
     nav#navbar, header{

       }
      nav#navbar ul{
          display: flex;
   }
       nav#navbar ul li{
         margin-left: 3rem;
      }
       nav#navbar ul li a{
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
        }
     #navbar a:hover{
background: white;
border:2px solid;
color: black;
         }
    @media screen and (max-width: 650px){
header{
    flex-direction: column;
    
}
nav#navbar ul{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
#header-img{
    margin: 1rem 0;
    text-align: center;
          }
     }


        container-intro{
text-align: center;

margin-top: 20rem;
      }
     .input {
       padding: 0.5rem;
        display: block;
           margin: 0.9rem auto;
          width: 300px;
       }
       .submit{
          width: 200px;
           padding: 0.5rem;
           display: block;
              margin: 0.9rem auto;
        font-size:1.5rem;
         border: none;
              text-transform: uppercase;
           font-weight: bold;
          background: orange;


   }
      #features{
         display: column;
     margin-top: 4rem;
      justify-content: center;

     align-items: center;

  }

       .desc{
      margin-top: 2rem;
    justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;

        }

        .prices {
 display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;


width: 33.33%;
  }
     .detail{
align-items: center;

justify-content: center;
     }
       .easy,.mid,.hard{
border: 1px solid black;

     }
        .video-div{
display:flex;
justify-content: space-between;
    }
      .video-div h1{
align-items: center;
justify-content: center; none of this working.
text-align: center;
     }
```

Comment: When I view the codepen, the navbar appears at the top and I can see the email section, so I'm not sure I understand your problem with that. As for the a:hover... Do you mean you want the entire link to fill the navbar from top to bottom around the link with a background color? Also, I don't see navlink class in your css. Could you share what type of hover css you have attempted for an example? Please clarify some of these issues. :)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to save. Can you check again?
"#navbar a:hover{
 background: white;
 border:2px solid;
 color: black;
}"

So usually it's box, border should cover its top and bottom right? And it is actually covers but cause I had to change background of header to make logo look like its on the navbar. I am sorry English is not my first language I think now you can see from the link what i tried to say. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I answered with what I think you are looking for. Please let me know if you have any questions, if it's not what you are looking for, or if you need more information and I will gladly update my answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**1. Navbar**

When placing the navbar with `position: fixed;` set the top location to `top: 0;` to prevent the space at the top. The email form wasn't set lower on the page because of a typo with the class name (the period was missing):

```
.container-intro{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20rem;
}
```

The `a` elements display inline by default, so if you want them to have height (for the hover to cover the top and bottom of the navbar color, as well) you can choose display: flex (for example) and switch the top and bottom padding (or margin) to the logo instead of having it it the navbar itself. I believe this is what you are trying to achieve for the navlinks. See my snippet for the code changes.

**2. Centering**

The container class should have `justify-content: center;` to center the desc classes. For the columns with borders, you have flex display on the prices but need to have a display value for their parent element (detail class).

Please review the code snippet and compare it to your codepen. I tried to provide enough comments in the code.

There are some helpful tips to working with flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.logo {
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
}


/* Added justify-content: center to center the features id: */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: orange;
  height: 500px;
}


/* Top and bottom padding prevented navlinks from reaching full-height, moved it to the logo */


/* With the fixed position, set the top to zero: */

header {
  padding: 0 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: orange;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#header-img {
  width: 15rem;
  margin-left: -1rem;
}

nav#navbar,
header {}


/* a elements display inline by default, so I changed it to flex and added height: */

.navlink {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

nav#navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

nav#navbar ul li {
  margin-left: 3rem;
  height: 100%;
}

nav#navbar ul li a {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid;
  color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  header {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  nav#navbar ul {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #header-img {
    margin: 1rem 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
}


/* This was missing the period before the class name: */

.container-intro {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20rem;
}

.input {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  display: block;
  margin: 0.9rem auto;
  width: 300px;
}

.submit {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  display: block;
  margin: 0.9rem auto;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: orange;
}

#features {
  display: column;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.desc {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.prices {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 33.33%;
}


/* Put the flex display on the detail class to make the prices classes centered: */

.detail {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.easy,
.mid,
.hard {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.video-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.video-div h1 {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  none of this working. text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--NAVBAR -->
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <img id="header-img" src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/product-landing-page-logo.png" alt="original trombones logo" />
    </div>
    <nav id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="navlink">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="navlink">Details</a></li>
        <li><a class="navlink">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>
  <div class="container-intro">
    <input type="email" required size="30" placeholder="Enter your email" class="input" id="email">
    <button type="Submit" class="submit" id: "submit">Submit</button>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <section id="features">

      <div class="desc">
        <h2>Premium Materials</h2>
        <p>
          Our trombones use the shiniest brass which is sourced locally. This will increase the longevity of your purchase.
        </p>
      </div>


      <div class="desc">
        <h2>Fast Shipping</h2>
        <p>
          We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.
        </p>
      </div>


      <div class="desc">
        <h2>Quality Assurance</h2>
        <p>
          For every purchase you make, we will ensure there are no damages or faults and we will check and test the pitch of your instrument.
        </p>
      </div>

    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="detail">
    <!--3 columns at the center of page -->
    <section class="prices">
      <div class="easy">
        <h2>Easy</h2>
        <ol>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <div class="mid">
        <h2>Medium</h2>
        <ol>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <div class="hard">
        <h2>Hard</h2>
        <ol>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <section class="video-section">
    <div class="video-div">
      <!--For the video h1 going to be on the left of the page and gonna be big and the video on the right -->
      <h1>The Video >>></h1>
      <div class="video">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5-9fAFjpncY?start=12" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

  <footer>
    <span>Copyright .....................</span>

  </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: This actually fixes all my problems, thank you. I'm gonna study the link you sent.  I don't have further questions, your answer covers everything. Have a good day/night.